# Generate a cell of random numbers in MATLAB, how?

Tags: matlab, random, cell-array

Let say I want to generate 3 matrices of size `3x4` each with random entries `rand(3, 4)`. How to put them in a `cell` `1x3`?

With a loop, it is easy:

```
A = cell(1, 3);
for i=1:3
   A{i}=rand(3, 4);
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store it in a 3 dimensional array:

```
A = rand(3,4,3);
```

Access the *i-th* layer with:

```
A(:,:,i)
```

Comment: Simple, easy and nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Code**

```
M = 3; %// Number of rows
N = 4; %// Number of columns
K = 3; %// Number of cells in the cell array output

A = permute(mat2cell(rand(M,N,K),M,N,ones(1,K)),[1 3 2]) %// output

celldisp(A) %// display cell array contents for verification
```

**Output**

```
A{1} =
    0.3477    0.2621    0.2428    0.3592
    0.1500    0.0445    0.4424    0.7363
    0.5861    0.7549    0.6878    0.3947
A{2} =
    0.6834    0.0196    0.2703    0.4299
    0.7040    0.3309    0.1971    0.8878
    0.4423    0.4243    0.8217    0.3912
A{3} =
    0.7691    0.7551    0.7904    0.6713
    0.3968    0.3774    0.9493    0.4386
    0.8085    0.2160    0.3276    0.8335
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) for this:

```
M = 3; %// Number of rows
N = 4; %// Number of columns
K = 3; %// Number of cells in the cell array output

arrayfun(@(n) rand(M,N), 1:K, 'UniformOutput',0)
```